# initializing an array of 20 elements to update values later, but some elements of the array start as non zero in C? why is that?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I was trying to solve problems from the C Programming Language by K&R currently on ex 1.13 and I noticed some odd behavior and I needed someone to explain to me why this is happening. If you look at the code below, it is a rough but working prototype to that problem.

The code works fine until a wordlength of 9. That is j<10 but if I increase the j loop to say j<20, trying to increase the wordlength it will display, it throws me in an infinite loop.

While trying to troubleshoot it, I noticed that it could happen because post initializing my array some elements inside my array were not 0 to begin with, is that normal? and if that is the
case why so ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int     c;
    unsigned int     i;
    unsigned int     j;
    unsigned int     k;
    unsigned int     array[30];
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    while((c= getchar())!= EOF)
    {
        if((c==' ')|| (c == '\t')||(c=='\n'))
        {
            array[i]++ ;
            i = 0;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(j=1;j<10;j++)
    {
        printf("%d \t",j);
        for(k=0; k< array[j]; k++)
        {
            putchar('-');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post how you performed the input.  The output seen and output expected.

Comment: Note that with `unsigned int array[30];`, `array[]` in uninitialized.

Comment: Please note that `getchar` returns an `int`, not an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsigned int array[30];` only declares an array of 30 slots.
If you want to initialize all values to 0, here's the syntax:

```
unsigned int array[30] = {0};
```

Comment: No, it's not, but before posting any question, make sure you can't find an answer easily elsewhere. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct to close the question. ;)